# How to solve NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, parsing

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('JOB205DAYREP.csv', header=0)
df = df.drop([0],axis=0)
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')

df.head(10)

df = pd.DataFrame({})

from dateutil.parser import parse
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(row['FLT']) or row ['FLT'] == 'NA':
        df.at[index, 'FLT'] = df.at[index-1, 'FLT']
    
    if pd.isnull(row['STD']) or row ['STD'] == 'NA':
        df.at[index,'STD'] = df.at[index-1, 'STD']

    else:
        row['STD'] = fltdate + row ['STD']
    if not index==0 :
        if pd.isnull(row['VIAOFF']) or row['VIAOFF'] == 'NA':
            df.at[index, 'VIAOFF'] = df.at[index-1, 'VIAOFF']
        if pd.isnull(row['DEP']) or row['DEP'] == 'NA':
            df.at[index, 'DEP'] = df.at[index-1, 'DEP']
df.head(10)

from dateutil.parser import parse
date_string = '21/01/2023'
try :
    if parse(date_string, fuzzy=True, dayfirst=True) is not None:
        print('The string is a valid date.')
    else:
        print('The string is not a valid date.')
except Exception as e:
    error ='error'
```

This code is reading in a CSV file using the **`read_csv()`** function from the **`pandas`** module, and dropping the first row, any rows with all missing values, and any columns with all missing values.

[Here is the csv data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFwp7.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZVe2.png)

Comment: Typo: `resad_csv` should be `read_csv`. Is that a copying error or in the real code?

Comment: Why are you doing `df = pd.DataFrame({})`? That's throwing away everything you read from the CSV and creating an empty dataframe.

Comment: Where, exactly, do you get that error?  Show the complete traceback.  If that is all one file, then it could not have produced that error.  If that's three separate files, then of course you get the error.

Comment: actually not, typo when i copy paste in here

Comment: i add output picture

Comment: The line numbers in the error don't match your source.  Perhaps you haven't saved your most recent changes.  Notice how it says "in line 2" -- again I suspect you have three different files, and `df` is not shared between them.

Answer (score 1):

The NameError: name 'df' is not defined error is raised because the df DataFrame is being re-assigned to an empty DataFrame in line #10:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({})
```

you can solve it removing that,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('JOB205DAYREP.csv', header=0)
df = df.drop([0],axis=0)
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if pd.isnull(row['FLT']) or row ['FLT'] == 'NA':
        df.at[index, 'FLT'] = df.at[index-1, 'FLT']
    
    if pd.isnull(row['STD']) or row ['STD'] == 'NA':
        df.at[index,'STD'] = df.at[index-1, 'STD']

    else:
        row['STD'] = fltdate + row ['STD']
    if not index==0 :
        if pd.isnull(row['VIAOFF']) or row['VIAOFF'] == 'NA':
            df.at[index, 'VIAOFF'] = df.at[index-1, 'VIAOFF']
        if pd.isnull(row['DEP']) or row['DEP'] == 'NA':
            df.at[index, 'DEP'] = df.at[index-1, 'DEP']

# Check if a string is a real valid date
from dateutil.parser import parse
date_string = '21/01/2023'
try :
    if parse(date_string, fuzzy=True, dayfirst=True) is not None:
        print('The string is a valid date.')
    else:
        print('The string is not a valid date.')
except Exception as e:
    error ='error'
```

Report back if it works now, hope it helps.